# how to fetch data of remote side database in hibernate using postgresql database

Tags: java, database, hibernate, postgresql

I am using Postgresql database. I need to know how to give connection url in hibernate.cfg.xml for remote connection.I gave below line.but I could not retrieve data from database.

```
 <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://hostIP:5432/databasename</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
```

Comment: Put the IP of host where DB is present

Comment: yeah I gave HostIP only... still it throws org.postgresql.util.psqlexception connection refused

Comment: please check the Host name and port are correct

Comment: try by connect from your machine, then check through code

Comment: is it working? or use my xml

Comment: Does the remote host even allow connections from outside? Is your IP whitelisted?

Answer (score 1):

Try below `hibernate.cfg.xml`and change the `HOSTIP` to your host IP where DB is present. and `DATABASENAME` with your database name and `username` and `password` accordingly.

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://HOSTIP:5432/DATABASENAME</property>



        <property name="connection_pool_size">1</property>

        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>



       <mapping class="org.javabrains.sanjaya.dto.UserDetails"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```